# Gradle JVM vs Project SDK settings in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, what is the difference between the Gradle JVM setting (first screenshot) and the Project SDK setting (second screenshot)?

Without IntelliJ, I sometimes do `./gradlew build` and I'm using Java 11 to build - which of the above settings does this translate to exactly? That is, what is the equivalent concept these two settings map to in the CLI? I think this would help me understand my initial question better.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When importing existing projects - IntelliJ uses the Project SDK version as the default Java for Gradle as well. but you can override if you wish.

seee https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_jvm